# Export one column in data grid view to notepad(.txt)

Tags: c#, asp.net, export

I have this code behind on my 'download button'. Yes, it downloads to notepad, but what i want is when the user clicks the 'download button', a SAVE-AS file dialogue will appear that can save and rename the file.please help!

```
   protected void btn_export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\SumTotal\file11.txt");

        int rowcount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[28].Text.ToString() + "\t");
        }
        sw.Close();     //Don't Forget Close the TextWriter Object(sw)
        Response.Write("Data Successfully Exported");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the browser display a file dialogue it it's not set up to. What you CAN do is add a textbox where the user can type in the file name they want. The only way you can do a Save-as dialogue is by using Flash or SilverLight. Or a java applet if you're feeling brave.